# Unity3D : Application.internetReachability always returns as NotReachable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

```
if(Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
{
    isConnected = true;
    Debug.Log("Success Connect");
}
else
{
    isConnected = false;
    Debug.Log("Failed Connect");
}
```

After updating Unity to the latest version, Application.internetReachability always returns NotReachable on Android phones.

There were no problems when using 2019.1.x, but problems arose from 2019.2.1 to the latest version.

Is there anything I need to do in the new version?

Please reply. Thank you.

Comment: [`Application.internetReachability`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-internetReachability.html) `Note: Do not use this property to determine the actual connectivity. E.g. the device can be connected to a hot spot, but not have the actual route to the network.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity check internet connection availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351155/unity-check-internet-connection-availability)

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931517/12065390).
I hope this works for you.