# How to Detect Android Connect WIFI but without Internet Connection

Tags: java, android

I work on Unity and I have problem cehcek Internet connection. I try to use function from unity https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-internetReachability.html . In document itselft said it's not realiable. I test it and yes, If you use this, when your device connect to WIFI without internet connection, above function will return true. So it's not realiable. My option right know is to detect internet connection from native for every platform. Right know I want to discuss for Android platform.

I create function to detect internet connection at Android platform. Everything is work as expected except when device is connect to WIFI without internet connection. My expectation it should return NO_CONNECTIVITY but it's return CONNECTIVITY_WIFI. Here is my code at java :

```
//for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23
int connectionType = CONNECTIVITY_UNKNOWN;

Network[] networksList = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
            int len = networksList.length;

            if(len == 0) {
                return NO_CONNECTIVITY;
            }

            for(Network network : networksList) {
                NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
                if(networkCapabilities == null) {
                    connectionType = NO_CONNECTIVITY;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    if(networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                            && !networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_WIFI_P2P)) {
                        if(connectionType != CONNECTIVITY_ETHERNET) {
                            connectionType = CONNECTIVITY_WIFI;
                        }
                    }
                    if(networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                        if(connectionType != CONNECTIVITY_WIFI) {
                            connectionType = CONNECTIVITY_CELLULAR;
                        }
                    }
                    if(networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                        connectionType = CONNECTIVITY_ETHERNET;
                    }
                }
            }

return connectionType;
```

There are some answer suggest to ping google to check the connection. I don't know that is the best approach, maybe there is another way from the android sdk ?

Comment: Although I'm unsure if pinging Google (or 8.8.8.8) is the best solution, I can vouch that it's reliable. So, if you don't have a problem waiting a few seconds to confirm whether the device is connected to the internet, I recommend this approach.